# Open a popup/alert before opening a link in the browser when clicked on a textview

Tags: android, textview

I'm using `Html.fromHtml(string)` to populate data into  textview. 
By setting the `textview.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance())` to the textview, it opens any links provided in the data automatically in the browser. But, I want to open a popup giving the user the option to continue with opening the link or cancel the process.

Answer (score -1):

You can write the below code:

```
textView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            //YOUR CODE TO OPEN LINK IN WEBVIEW

            alert.dismiss();
        }
    });

    alert.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            alert.dismiss();
        }
    });
    alert.setTitle("ANY TITLE");
    alert.setMessage("ANY MESSAGE");

    alert.show();
});
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: hanks..but, If I set the textview to onclickListener(), then even if my text has not link data, the alert will open..the dialog box should open only when clicked on a hyper link in a textview.

Comment: yes dude, you need to make your own logic to achieve any particular requirement. So you need to check the data of the textview and according to that you need to create if...else in onclick event.