# Open a dialog from a hyperlink on text view - Android

Tags: android, hyperlink, dialog, textview

There is a way to put a link in some words on a textView and when i click on this word, a dialog is open.

Ex.: TextView --> Word A - Word B - Word C

When i click on Word A, show a Dialog with some options, and when i click on Word C open another dialog with another options.

i checked this link but my problem dont fits.

[Open a popup/alert before opening a link in the browser when clicked on a textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17850372/open-a-popup-alert-before-opening-a-link-in-the-browser-when-clicked-on-a-textvi)

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 6):

Suppose you are given a `“this is a test”` `String` and you wish to show dialog A for the substring `“this”` and dialog B for the substring `“test”`. Consider the following method:

```
private static void applySpan(SpannableString spannable, String target, ClickableSpan span) {
  final String spannableString = spannable.toString();
  final int start = spannableString.indexOf(target);
  final int end = start + target.length();
  spannable.setSpan(span, start, end, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
}
```

The method takes a `spannable`, searches for the first `target` occurrence in it and applies the `span` to it. To show the `spannable` in a `TextView`, say from an `Activity`, you could do the following:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    final SpannableString spannable = SpannableString.valueOf(“this is a test”);
    applySpan(spannable, "this", new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
            // show dialog A
        }
    });
    applySpan(spannable, "test", new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
            // show dialog B
        }
    });

    final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setText(spannableString);
    textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

    setContentView(textView);
}
```

This is just a crude example, but it hopefully demonstrates a way to solve your problem.